# Find Tables in PDF's

Tags: c#, pdf, information-retrieval

Are there any tools or tricks how to automatically extract tables from pdfs. Are there any C# libraries that could do that? Or do you maybe know other methods how this could be handled?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found a interesting site and one master thesis about this topic

Information Extraction - Utilizing Table Patterns

http://ieg.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/projects/pdf2table/

if anybody finds more informations please keep on posting...

Answer (score 1):

PDF files do not contain table structures - several tools will try and 'guess' them.